# calling layout() from ResizeObserver doesn't work but calling from window.onResize does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, resize, monaco-editor

In my react application, give `editors` is an array of all editors created with `monaco.editor.create()` that are currently opened in the application, let's say I have this:

```
const resizeObserver = useRef(new ResizeObserver(entries => {
    console.log('entries = ', entries);
    for(let entry of entries) {
        console.log('target = ', entry.target);
        const editor = getEditor(entry.target.id);
        console.log('editor = ', editor);
        editor.layout({} as monaco.editor.IDimension);
    }
  }));
```

it fires properly but the editor isn't resized. But let's say I'd resize only the current editor:

```
window.onresize = () => {
  const editor = editors[0];
  editor.layout({} as monaco.editor.IDimension);
}
```

this works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: All these editors are on a single page?

Comment: it's within tabs so only one show a time

Comment: Which means you effectively have only one editor in the DOM. How can all the others re-layout, if they don't exist at that moment?

Answer (score 1):

In a React application, when you only have one visible editor on a page, only use one editor. Don't store editor instances somewhere for manipulations, when they are not visible. Instead use `componentDidMount` to load a new model in the (only) editor instance and save state of the editor in `componentUpdated`. [Here's a code editor component, which does all that.](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-shell-plugins/blob/master/gui/frontend/src/components/ui/CodeEditor/CodeEditor.tsx#L358)

For the resize operation use a resize observer in the editor component. Set it up in its constuctor:

```js
        if (typeof ResizeObserver !== "undefined") {
            this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(this.handleEditorResize);
        }
```

and handle the resize in that editor component like this:

```js
    private handleEditorResize = (entries: readonly ResizeObserverEntry[]): void => {
        if (entries.length > 0) {
            const rect = entries[0].contentRect;
            this.editor?.layout({ width: rect.width, height: rect.height });
        }
    };
```

Don't forget to clean up when the component is unmounted:

```js
    public componentWillUnmount(): void {
        ...
        this.resizeObserver?.unobserve(this.hostRef.current as Element);
    }
```